# Refresh Fragment after preferences changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager within a Fragment which contains three Fragments we'll call V1, V2 and V3. 
Besides, in the ActionBar there is a button that sends the user to a SharedPreferencesActivity.

That Activity just contains two options, an IP and a port. I want to control if the Preferences are actually specified, some controls will be enabled on V1, V2 and V3 but if they're not they'll remain disabled.

How can I do this? Right now I check this in the `onCreateView()` but how can I do if the user write an IP/Host and a port when they press back and go back to the main Fragment with the PageViewer its embeded fragments re-check this preferences and behave consquently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the code that enables/disables those controls out into its own method, then call that method in onCreateView(), and in onResume().

Comment: This is what I was thinking but somehow I didn't see the onResume() method on the Fragments documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Ah-  Here's a link:) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code in `onResume()`.  From the developer's page about `Fragments`:

> **onCreateView():**
>
> The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

If you are simply going back to the Fragment from another window it might be a safer bet to do this in `onResume()`.

Some more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Ok, I'll try. This is what I was thinking but somehow I didn't see the onResume() method on the Fragments documentation.

Thank you!